# Why does Automator just not work?! Like it just fails

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I record a macro with Automator....and then I run it back and it completely misses everything.....what is going on here?!?

https://streamable.com/tyed9

Comment: Does it do the same thing if the Dock is not hidden?  Really, **Watch Me Do** is one of those last-ditch-can't-find-anything-else-that-works actions, and even then you should keep looking.

Comment: @red_menace sounds like you know more about this than I do ;-) all I want to do is what you see in the video, open an app and choose an item in its file menu. Is there a better way to script it?

Comment: A regular AppleScript can be used, and it looks like you are using Keyboard Maestro, which is also scriptable.

Answer (score 0):

The **Automator** *workflow* with the **Watch Me Do** *action* that you've recorded requires the **Dock** to be unhidden for it to function properly.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will click the target *menu item*:

```
activate application "Keyboard Maestro"
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    click menu item "Launch Engine" of ¬
        menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of ¬
        menu bar 1 of ¬
        application process "Keyboard Maestro"
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

---

**You could also assign *keyboard shortcuts* as in the example image below:**

**System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **App Shortcuts**

[image]

That said, I do not use **Keyboard Maestro**, however you probably could use it also to accomplish what you want.

Comment: As you stated, you don't use _Keyboard Maestro_ so there's no way you would know that the _Keyboard Maestro Engine_ is itself an app, which it itself scriptable (although that last part isn't relevant).  But it means the UI scripting bits can be replaced with `launch application "Keyboard Maestro Engine"`